# How to add a line break in dynamically generated control in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm working on a small project where I want to show PictureBox on a panel programmatically although somehow I have achieved this thanks to StackOverflow now the problem is I want only 4 to 5 picture boxes should be visible at the first line and the next box on the second line and so on and so forth
here is my code for adding pictures box in pannel

```
Try
    Dim numberOfPics As Integer = images.Count
    Dim lastLeft As Integer = 15
    Const spacer As Integer = 5

    For parser As Integer = 1 To numberOfPics - 1
        Dim PicBox As New PictureBox
        PicBox.Width = 88
        PicBox.Height = 135
        PicBox.Top = 25
        PicBox.Left = lastLeft
        lastLeft = PicBox.Width + PicBox.Left + spacer
        PicBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
        PicBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(PicBox)
        Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
        Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(images.Item(parser).Groups(1).Value)))
        PicBox.Image = tImage
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
End Try
```

This code show picture boxes in a single row like this
[Code Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DL2sz.png)

I have tried my best to explain my problem but still, If I miss something then let me know my mistake.

Comment: [FlowLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel?view=net-5.0).

Comment: For the record, I'm viewing this on a phone and half your code is obscured because you've included a fat wad of leading whitespace for no good reason. You should do what you can to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code helps you to understand how to achieve your goal. So, start from this and improve:
(Some comments in code)

```
    Try

        Const spacer As Integer = 5

        ' Here max elements x row
        Dim elementsXRow As Integer = 3

        Dim numberOfPics As Integer = 11 'images.Count

        Dim lastLeft As Integer = 15
        Dim lastTop As Integer = 25
        Dim w As Integer = 88
        Dim h As Integer = 138

        For parser As Integer = 0 To numberOfPics - 1

            ' If parser is like 3 + 3 + 3 you need to start from point 0 -> means lastLeft - > 15
            If parser > 0 AndAlso parser Mod elementsXRow = 0 Then
                ' so restart your coordinates
                lastLeft = 15
                lastTop += h + spacer
            End If


            'Dim tClient As WebClient = New WebClient
            'Dim tImage As Bitmap = Bitmap.FromStream(New MemoryStream(tClient.DownloadData(images.Item(parser).Groups(1).Value)))

            Dim PicBox As New PictureBox With {
                .Width = w,
                .Height = h,
                .Top = lastTop,
                .Left = lastLeft,
                .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage,
                .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                .Image = Nothing 'tImage
            }

            lastLeft = PicBox.Width + PicBox.Left + spacer

            Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(PicBox)



        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
    End Try

End Sub
```

To have 4 elements x row you can simply change `elementsXRow = 4`

Comment: I did the same thing as you mention in the above code but the above code is printing only 4 PictureBox like this [link](https://anonfiles.com/bcO4X5x7u9/Capture_PNG)

Comment: Increase the height of Panel. If them are more of 4 then them are somewhere down invisibile. Have fun